# Java Inheritance: should an extension of a class inherit the class?

Tags: java, design-patterns, inheritance, subclass, extends

For my current project, I'm making a wrapper for the java `File` class, as well as a wrapper for a path `String` (ie. `C:\Users\Public\`).
Let's call the wrapper for the `File` class `FileWrapper` and the wrapper for a path `PathWrapper`.

`FileWrapper` obviously must have a path: the location of `FileWrapper`'s `File` on the disk. Now my question is...
Should `FileWrapper` contain a field of type `PathWrapper` (and an accessor method for `PathWrapper`'s `PathWrapper.getPath()`), or should it extend `PathWrapper`, therefore inheriting the `getPath()` method?

The issue I'm having is that `FileWrapper`, strictly speaking, isn't a `Path`. It's just a file. But it seems simpler to just use inheritance anyway in this case.

There is another issue with the second solution I was considering (create a `getPath()` method in `FileWrapper`). I would like to create a `Path` interface that `FileWrapper` and `PathWrapper` would both implement, in order to allow generic lists of both `FileWrapper`s and `PathWrapper`s.
If `FileWrapper` was a subclass of `PathWrapper`, this interface would not be necessary.

Comment: doesn't `java.io.File` already have methods to get the path and/or absolute path? And if your `FileWrapper.class` is a wrapper of a `File`, then just call that method natively... no?

Comment: FileWrapper.getPath() would return a PathWrapper instance, which contains fancy methods, such as one for checking if a given PathWrapper is inside a folder defined by another PathWrapper.

Comment: The reverse would also be handy `PathWrapper.getFile()`.

Comment: If the behavior you want to have is more concrete or more well-known than your your implementation of that behavior, or if you can anticipate multiple flavors of implementation, then an interface-based type system is the way to go in situations where there is -not- a tight, well-defined "is a" relationship in your data.  If there is no such focus on the desired behavior, then the right approach is conposition (which is what a wrapper implies in any case).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**OO Design Rule :** Favor Composition over inheritence, as composition (Has-a relations) allows more flexibility to your code

Also as you say, `FileWrapper` is not a `PathWrapper`, you answered your question.

You want to bind them together, you can pass a `PathWrapper` to the constructor of the `FileWrapper`.

For example, if you want to get both in a *Collection*, you can make a *Wrapper* interface, where `FileWrapper` and `PathWrapper` are siblings in this hierarchy, and share common abstract methods that can be implemented differently by each of them.

Many design patterns can be applied to this example, all what you need to do is decide what you want first.

Answer (score 2):

> The issue I'm having is that `FileWrapper`, strictly speaking, isn't a `Path`. It's just a file.

That's the only consideration that you need: once you say that logically a `FileWrapper` is *not* a `Path`, you should exclude inheritance from your list of choices.

That is not to say that you shouldn't give `FileWrapper` a `getPath` method, though: if you find it more convenient to have `getPath` right on the `FileWrapper` class, then it makes perfect sense to add the method.

> I would like to create a "Path" interface that `FileWrapper` and `PathWrapper` would both implement, in order to allow generic lists of both `FileWrappers` and `PathWrappers`.

That sounds like a good idea. An interface is a nice, lightweight alternative to subclassing that makes more sense in your situation. Properly named, such an interface would add clarity to your overall system, without adding confusion associated with doubtful inheritance.

Comment: I know that traditionally, we make that distinction. In this case however, it seems messy to make a Path interface with only one line in it.

Comment: @kryo You may want to give `Path` interface a different name - say, `PathSource` or something similar, showing that the object *has* a path (therefore, letting you call `getPath()`) rather than *being* a path itself.

Comment: Yeah Path isn't a very good name, I just haven't come up with a very descriptive name at this time.